# Ctrl - C no longer copies. Any ideas?

Tags: vim, remapping

In the course of trying to remap Vim, I destroyed the copy shortcut. I deleted `.vimrc` and checked the settings shortcuts and I can't get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to work any more no matter what.

Comment: If you're using Gnome-Terminal, try copying with Shift-Ctrl-C instead

Comment: that seems to open developer tools instead

Comment: That's because you pressed it in your web browser instead of in gnome-terminal. Maybe I misunderstood because of your notes about your .vimrc -- are you saying Ctrl-C doesn't work In other applications outside the terminal, such as your web browser? If that's the case (and if it worked before), you changed something other than your .vimrc. It would be helpful to know what exactly you did.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying.  Thanks for the tip on ctrl-shift-c I'll use that in the terminal, but for solving the larger problem, any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. Retrace your steps :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you in mouse active mode in vi? That will prevent ctl-shift-c from copying. Try this from within vi and then try to copy again:

```
:set mouse=
```